# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /root,\"" + path + "\""); not working when path contains folder with two blank spaces

Tags: java

Good morning,

I have a JWS component to open some shared folder from a Java Web app.

The only code that runs the JWS is this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /root,\"" + path + "\"");`

It usually works like a charm, but, when the path contains a folder with two consecutive blank spaces, the "My Documents" folder is opened instead. That's how it works explorer.exe for non existent folders, it opens the "My Documents" folder. But in this case, the folder exists!

For example:

`String path = "C:\\Prueba  doble  espacio\\";`

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /root,\"" + path + "\"");`

If I run this code, the "My Documents" folder opens in the explorer.

But if I open the CMD and runs this:

`C:\>explorer.exe /root,"C:\Prueba  doble  espacio\"`

The proper C:\Prueba  doble  espacio\ is opened in the explorer instead.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that's what I do before and after the + path + , I tried your code for double surrounding, but the same happens. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @g00se but I don't understand. I explain in my post that in cmd.exe the command ```explorer.exe /root,"C:\Prueba  doble  espacio\"``` works properly. What else are you asking for? I will check ```ProcessBuilder```, thank you.

Comment: ```ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/root","C:\\Prueba  doble  espacio");```  will probably do it for you (except of course that's not a proper path for JWS)

Comment: Thanks @g00se , but your code doesn't even compile. Changing the ```\``` to ```\\``` compiles, but does nothing. No explorer opens.

Comment: Perhaps don't respond to my comments *quite* so quickly ;) I made the correction. **A** what is your *actual* url and **B** what was the rest of the code using what I posted?

Comment: @g00se ok, sorry, it's my fist post ;) **A** my actual path is ```C:\Prueba doble espacio\``` **B** the code I tried was: ```public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {``` ```ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/root", "C:\\Prueba  doble  espacio");``` ```}```. Am I missing something?

Comment: That code won't do a thing. You didn't call ```ProcessBuilder.start``` The first thing you should do when faced with unfamiliar classes is check out the Javadoc. In the case of ```ProcessBuilder``` it is extensive and will show you exactly how to use it

Comment: Ok @g00se, my bad, sorry. I added ```pb.start();``` and now it opens the "My Documents" folder. Thank you very much, but ```ProccessBuilder``` works exactly the same way as ```Runtime.getRuntime().exec()```.

Comment: *...but ProccessBuilder works exactly the same...* it does in essence but it's much more flexible and easier to control, particularly in regard to stdout and stderr

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"explorer.exe", "/root,", "\"" + path + "\""});`

Instead of:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /root,\"" + path + "\"");`

That solves the problem. What's the reason why? Who knows...

Thank you!

Comment: The simple answer is that in your original code the runtime has to try to split the arguments by spaces and in your fixed way you already tell the OS how the values should be split. I *think* you should also be fine if you removed the added quotes to the path and simply add the path itself as the 3rd element of the `String[]`.